# Rest-Assured form Authentication not working

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured, web-api-testing

I am trying to use rest-assured for one of my application the problem is I am not able to authenticate.

Following is the code I am trying

```
baseURI = "http://localhost:8080/api";
given()
        .auth().form("admin", "admin", new FormAuthConfig("/authentication/", "j_username", "j_password"))
.when()
        .get("/formAuth")
        .then()
        .log().all()
        .statusCode(200);
```

I have tried following options as well, nothing works out 
**401 error for following and above code**

```
form("admin", "admin", new FormAuthConfig("/", "j_username", "j_password"))
```

following option is not working, shows Failed to parse login page. Check for errors on the login page or specify FormAuthConfig. error

```
.auth().form("admin", "admin", formAuthConfig().withAutoDetectionOfCsrf())
```

Following is the code for form

```
<form class="form ng-pristine ng-valid" role="form" ng-submit="login($event)">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username" translate="global.form.username" class="ng-scope">Login</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" id="username" placeholder="Your login" ng-model="username" autocomplete="off">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password" translate="login.form.password" class="ng-scope">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" id="password" placeholder="Your password" ng-model="password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="rememberMe">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="rememberMe" ng-model="rememberMe" checked="" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
                        <span translate="login.form.rememberme" class="ng-scope">Automatic Login</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ng-scope" translate="login.form.button">Authenticate</button>
            </form>
```

And following is the captures output using **PostMan**

```
URL: http://localhost:8080/api/authentication?cacheBuster=1485280599118
parameter:  j_username:admin
j_password:admin
```

Comment: why names starts with 'j_' if your from has fields without it?

Answer (score 0):

Something seems broken in v3. I had same issue today when moving from com.jayway.restassured 2.8.0 to io.restassured 3.0.5. I just rolled back the upgrade and it worked again :/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to provide more information on how the authentication call is carried out.

When you defined the `new FormAuthConfig("/authentication/", "j_username", "j_password")`, you're telling Rest Assured that it should make a POST call to an `/authentication` endpoint using the two last parameters as form params.

Usually, the HTML `<form>` element has an `action` attribute indicating the endpoint to which it will make the POST request and the `name` attribute in the `<input>` tags indicate the keys of the form params that should be used.

In your case, the HTML form doesn't provide much information about how the call is being made, since it's probably handled with Javascript.

By the way, just a side note, it's often useful enable logging when defining the `FormAuthConfig` as follows:

```
given().auth()
  .form(
    "admin",
    "admin",
    new FormAuthConfig("/authentication", "j_username", "j_password")
      .withLoggingEnabled())
  // ...
```